# Xcode Unit Testing run function correctly

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing

Let's say I have this test code

```
class MyTests: XCTestCase {

    // I want to call this func first when I run class test.
    func testLoginUser() {
        ... do some test
        ... expectation.fulfiil() // jump to the next testGetUserProfile func.
    }

    // I want to run this func after testLoginUser fulfill expectation
    func testGetUserProfile() {

    }
}
```

Questions:

1. As I understood that all functions which started from prefix test will be called automatically by pressing this button on the image below with undefined queue of calls. So `testGetUserProfile` func can be called before actually `testLoginUser` fulfilled am I right?
2. If so then does it mean that I need to rename `testGetUserProfile` to `getUserProfile` function and call it from `testLoginUser` after expectation fulfilled?
   [image]

Is there a way to program a queue of test func calls one by one after each of them fulfilled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of test method execution is defined by their names, by default Xcode runs them in alphabetical order.

Xcode 11 has introduced Test Plans, where you can configure the execution order to be either "random" or "alphabetical".

Comment: ok got it, so then if I need to follow some specific order then I need to name the func alphabetically or call next func after fulfill() execution, correct?

Comment: Yes. Note that if you call the method yourself, you should rename it to not be called again by the test suite.